# Creating a reusable jQuery date formatter

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have the following jQuery which I use to format a date to be parsed to the DB (forward slashes don't work) in a format Rails will accept.

```
$('input#expClosingDateDisplay').change(function() {

    var expClosingDateDisplay = $(this).val().split('/');

    var formattedexpClosingDate = expClosingDateDisplay[2] + '-' + expClosingDateDisplay[1] + '-' + expClosingDateDisplay[0]                                            

    $('input#expClosingDate').val('');

    if (expClosingDateDisplay != '') {
        $('input#expClosingDate').val(formattedexpClosingDate);
    }

});
```

html

```
<input id="expClosingDateDisplay" class="fdatepicker" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" value="<%= @real_property_sale_project.expected_closing_date.try(:strftime, "%d/%m/%Y") %>">
<%= f.hidden_field :expected_closing_date, id: "expClosingDate" %>
```

This works as it should but I would like to use this function throughout my application as I have a number of date fields. How would I go about turning my current jQuery implementation into a reusable function?

Comment: The question in my previous comment has an answer that I hope will help you out. Does that thread address your question, or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Have you considered using one of various jquery datepicker libraries? They  allow you to format the date as configured and provide a nice calendar UI to select the date.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a jQuery global function isn't too tough (make sure this executes before any js that'll need it):

```
jQuery.fn.yourAwesomeFunction = function() {
  // your awesome function code goes here
};
```

And to use it:

```
$('.some-selector').yourAwesomeFunction();
```

Hope this helps!