# Reusable jQuery date manipulator function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845377/creating-a-reusable-jquery-date-formatter) previously. I have since made some progress but have run into a problem. I'm trying to create a reusable function that manipulates the users inputted date and returns the date in a different format into a hidden field. My implementation works correctly for the first date field but it's also returning the same value into my other hidden fields with the same class name?

```
$.fn.convertDate = function() {

    var dateIn      = $('input.datedisplay').val().split('/');
    var dateOut     = dateIn[2] + '-' + dateIn[1] + '-' + dateIn[0]

    if (dateIn != '') {
        $(this).closest('div.row').find('input.dateselect').val(dateOut);
    }
};


$(document).on('change', function() {
   $('input.datedisplay').convertDate();
});


<div class="row collapse">
  <label>Date label</label>
  <div class="small-3 large-2 columns">
    <span class="prefix"><%= icon('fa fa-calendar-o') %></span>
  </div>
  <div class="small-9 large-10 columns">
    <input class="datedisplay fdatepickernew" type="text" value="">
    <input class="dateselect" type="hidden" value="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row collapse">
  <label>Date label</label>
  <div class="small-3 large-2 columns">
    <span class="prefix"><%= icon('fa fa-calendar-o') %></span>
  </div>
  <div class="small-9 large-10 columns">
    <input class="datedisplay fdatepickernew" type="text" value="">
    <input class="dateselect" type="hidden" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the jquery script that you use to implement the convertDate.

Comment: `$('input.datedisplay')` returns an array of all inputs that have `datedisplay` class. Therefore when you call `val().split()`, just the first element of the array will be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` if you plugin is initialized by `input.datedisplay` itself like,

```
var dateIn  = $(this).val().split('/');
```

Otherwise, it will give the correct date for your current targeted element.

Also, you should check length of array like,

```
if (dateIn.length) {// as is an array not a string
```

```js
$.fn.convertDate = function () {
    var dateIn = $(this).val().split('/');
    var dateOut = dateIn[2] + '-' + dateIn[1] + '-' + dateIn[0];
    if (dateIn != '') {
        $(this).closest('div.row').find('input.dateselect').val(dateOut);
    }
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.datedisplay').on('change', function () {
        $(this).convertDate()
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row collapse">
    <label>Date label</label>
    <div class="small-9 large-10 columns">
        <input class="datedisplay fdatepickernew" type="text" value=""/>
            <input class="dateselect" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row collapse">
    <label>Date label</label>
    <div class="small-9 large-10 columns">
        <input class="datedisplay fdatepickernew" type="text" value=""/>
        <input class="dateselect" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you I have updated that part but the dateOut is still return in both `.dateselect` hidden fields.

Comment: I'm in the process of setting one up but the above solution still doesn't work. It's returning the value into both of the hidden fields.

Comment: You should try,
`$(document).ready(function() {  
   $('input.datedisplay').on('change',function(){$(this).convertDate()});
});` And with my change `var dateIn  = $(this).val().split('/');`

Comment: That fixed it - thank you! I don't entirely understand why this worked could you please explain?

Comment: Actually you are binding `convertDate` for all `datedisplay` on changing of any `datedisplay` which is ambiguous. So the coorect way is to bind only the element which is actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
var dateIn = $('input.datedisplay').val().split('/');
```

to

```
var dateIn = $(this).closest('div.row').find('input.datedisplay').val().split('/');
```